# SELECT query inside html code gets no results

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to install php code inside html file that will present all the club friends by using SELECT query for MySQL. can't see the results inside the page. need help. Here's the entire php code (and some html) the integrated inside html:

```
<h2> Club Members</h2>
<br/>
<table dir="ltr" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td><b>Private Name</b></td>
<td><b>Family Name</b></td>
<td><b>E-mail</b></td>
  </tr>

   <?php

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"");

//Check if the connection was opened, if not prompt the error to the page.
if (!$conn)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//Select the data base.
mysqli_select_db($conn, "Club");

//Set the character set to utf-8 to allow hebrew.
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

//SQL query - user Details  
    $sql = "SELECT Fname, Lname, Mail FROM customers";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["Fname"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Lname"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Mail"] ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the client or server? Are you running this on an actual web server or just locally?

Comment: i'm using Apache server by XAMPP. using it for my degree studies.       b/t/w, when using INSERT query with other php file,  it works great

Comment: @JasonB you need to specify that you want to fetch the results by providing the parameter that allows fetching the results as an associative array; see the online manual at php.net.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you've missed to include the connection link variable to your query and error functions. e.g.

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
```

vs

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: I added a mysql database and table with the same columns that you use, corrected the $conn variable missing on mysqli_query() and mysqli_error() and I have it working. I had some local issues with mysqli not being installed, and if your server doesn't print errors it can be worth adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your script to force error reporting in case you have some similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

**I have rewritten your code in MySQLi Object-oriented** *but I highly recommend PHP PDO for a faster and more reliable solution*.

Just replace your old code with my code below.

```
<h2> Club Members</h2>
<br/>
<table dir="ltr" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td><b>Private Name</b></td>
<td><b>Family Name</b></td>
<td><b>E-mail</b></td>
  </tr>
<?php
//recoded in MySQLi Object-oriented by Ajmal PraveeN
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "Club";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["Fname"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Lname"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Mail"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo '</table>';
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank for the code, but still no results inside the table at the xhtml page

Comment: Give me the screenshots of errors or result page and the Output source view

Comment: You've mixed procedural and object oriented mysqli styles in your rewrite.I think that It'd be more productive to explain why he needed to switch style in the first place and refer to the documentation instead.

Comment: Im waiting for his Reply.. and Yosh, did you checked my code with some other DB Query whether it works or not? Jason old code is not written in correct format. You are saying im mixed and Need explain. So you Need comments? or Working code?